# What is the difference between a UX Architect and a UX Designer?

Tags: information-architecture, users

I am not so sure what is the difference between ux-architect and a ux-designer?

UX-Architect
- involved in research
- create wire frames + interactive wireframes
- create guidelines
- involved with other stack holders
- etc

UX-Designer
- involved in research
- create wire frames + interactive wireframes
- create mock-up design + interactive design
- create guidelines
- involved with other stack holders
- etc

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be referring to the term: [*Information Architect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design#Information_architecture).

It is an element of User Experience Design, which concerns itself with Usability and Findability.

[image: elements]

UX concerns itself with various such elements which come under it, but nowadays Startups like to refer the job listing as UI/UX Designer/ UX Architect due to negligence or to specify the exact requirement they have regarding UX.

As a UX Designer, you are expected to know all the elements, but as an Architect, you should be *specializing* in Information Architecture in UX.

Comment: Good one. This is, by the way, a MUST ASK question in each and every interview for a job that is UX related: How does your new employer define "UX" and the job description you applied for. It got too much of a buzz word, and everyone wants a piece of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched and found [Benny Skogberg](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4679/benny-skogberg) explanation.

Jan 31, 2014 : just like to share
[Can Information Architects and UX Designers work as separate profiles?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51381/can-information-architects-and-ux-designers-work-as-separate-profiles)

Information Architecture is a more specialized role than User Experience Designer. They can very well work together in the same project where the UXD deals with everything but IA core competences. You can look at the UXD as the project lead in IA related questions where IA deals with core IA tasks.

Differences between Information Architecture and User Experience Design

Jesse James Garret, author of "The Elements of User Experience", made an infamous visualization on User Experience elements before writing his book. It has two different scales: Abstract to Concrete- scale and Conception to Completion-scale. It's divided into five layers which should be read from the bottom and upward (from Conception to Completion and from Abstract to Concrete over time).

Download the [original PDF](http://www.jjg.net/ia/elements.pdf) from March 30, 2000.

It reflects the process of designing any artifact from a User Experience perspective. Garret highlights what is important at each layer and each stage of the project. Beware though, this image should not be seen as a project roadmap where you complete one layer before moving on to the next. Garret states though that you can't finish one layer before preceding layers are finished. You need to be agile and move between layers as you move along.

It is possible to transfer these layers into different competencies. The User Experience Designer cover all of these aspects of the visualization:

- Site Objectives and User Needs
- Functional Specification and Content Requirements
- Interaction Design and Information Architecture
- Information Design, Interface Design and Navigation Design
- Visual Design

The Information Architect (IA) is a more specialized area of User Experience. In short an Information Architect "connects people to the content they're looking for". To do this the IA have four different tools:

- Classification and Hierarchy
- Labels and Tagging
- Navigation and
- Wayfinding Search